# Possible to send message for status change

Tags: mx-notify

Should it be possible to send a notification in mx notify control if the status of an entry changes from x to y?

I can get it to send if an entry with status x is updated but I only want it to send when the status specifically changes from x to y.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple addon, if you don't see that option, it's probably not built in.

Quickest solution would be to roll a quick extension and hook it to the `entry_submission_ready` hook. Then check statuses, and use the email class to shoot out an email.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#entry-submission-ready

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/email.html

Something simple like:

```
function my_extension_entry_submission_ready($meta, $data, $autosave)
{
    // submitted updated status
    $status_new = $meta["status"];

    // get previous status
    $status_old = ee()->db->select('status')
                          ->from('channel_titles')
                          ->where('entry_id', $meta['entry_id'])
                          ->get()->row_array();

    $status_old = $status_old['status'];

    // do we meet your conditions?
    if ($status_old == "desired_old_status" &&
        $status_new == "desired_new_status")
    {
        // send email using the email class        
    }
}
```

Not sure if that hook hits new submissions (which wouldn't have an entry_id), so you'll have to play around to get it right (a few extra conditionals so you can bail if it's a new entry).